# Azure AD Access Token - Authorization Code is malformed or invalid

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I have a web app with C# backend trying to get the Access Token from Azure AD. Using https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token. I have got the authorization code, but when requesting the Access Token I get this respons:

```
error: invalid_grant

error_description: AADSTS70000: Transmission data parser failure: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid.
```

I have checked that the redirect url is the exact same as the one I use in the request for the authorization code. And both redirect_uri, app_id_uri and client secret is url encoded.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";

        string parameter = "code=" + code;
        parameter += "&client_id=" + client_id;
        parameter += "&client_secret=" + client_secret;
        parameter += "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri;
        parameter += "&grant_type=authorization_code";
        parameter += "&resource=" + app_id_uri;

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(parameter);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream datastream = request.GetRequestStream();
        datastream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        datastream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                return line;
            }
        }
```

UPDATE:

This is the request to get the authorization code:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&response_mode=fragment&scope=openid&state=microsoftoauth&nonce=7362CAEA-9CA5-4B43-9BA3-34D7C303EBA7
```

Comment: Try a new request to the `/authorize` endpoint.

Comment: @SunnySun-MSFT I do a new one for each request, not reusing the code.

Comment: After requesting a new authorization code and using the new code to request token, it still prompts the same error?

Comment: @SunnySun-MSFT Yeah, same thing.

Comment: could you share your request for authorization code here?

Comment: @SunnySun-MSFT I have updated  the original post with the request.

Answer (score 1):

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&response_mode=fragment&scope=openid&state=microsoftoauth&nonce=7362CAEA-9CA5-4B43-9BA3-34D7C303EBA7

From your request, I find your request is just for id_token, not include the authorization code, that's why prompts the code invalid, so you need to add `code` into the code request `response_type=id_token+code`.

Comment: If there is anything to update, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: If the answer is useful for you, please help mark it, thanks.